# Helm Release with existing resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Previously we only use `helm template` to generate the manifest and apply to the cluster, recently we start planning to use `helm install` to manage our deployment, but running into following problems:

Our deployment is a simple backend api which contains "Ingress", "Service", and "Deployment", when there is a new commit, the pipeline will be triggered to deploy.
We plan to use the short commit sha as the image tag and helm release name. Here is the command
`helm upgrade --install releaseName repo/chartName -f value.yaml --set image.tag=SHA`

This runs perfectly fine for the first time, but when I create another release it fails with following error message

```
rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: Service "app-svc" in namespace "ns" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "rel-124": current value is "rel-123"
```

The error message is pretty clear on what the issue is, but I am just wondering what's "correct" way of using helm in this case?

It is not practical that I uninstall everything for a new release, and I also dont want to keep using the same release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already doing it "right" way, just don't change `release-name`. That's key for Helm to identify resources. It seems that you previously used different name for release (`rel-123`) then you are using now (`rel-124`).

To fix your immediate problem, you should be able to proceed by updating value of annotation `meta.helm.sh/release-name` on problematic resource. Something like this should do it:

```
kubectl annotate --overwrite service app-svc meta.helm.sh/release-name=rel-124
```

Comment: appreciate the help, i think i mis-understand the concept of release. I thought the releaseName is something that keeps track the version, I believe we can use the same releaseName but different chart version + app version to keep track of the version